# How to separate two values inside a array and make them its own value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I hope my question isnt confusing but I have a js array:

`0:"Glass" 1:"LDPE" 2:"LDPE, PP" 3:"PP"`

And as you can see number 2 has two values in it, I would want them to be its own value basically to look like:

`0:"Glass" 1:"LDPE" 2:"LDPE" 3: PP" 4:"PP"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the items.

```js
var array = ["Glass", "LDPE", "LDPE, PP", "PP"];

array = array.join(', ').split(', ');

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Hello Nina, thank you for the code snippet, I tried it and it worked.